# Disable or Reset .Net Framework Init Error

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, installation

I am writing some code in .net 4.5  All good, then I go to install and the computer is from 1945 and can only go up to 4.0.  No biggie, so I start re-working the code a bit.  And send up a test.  And I get the .NET Framework Initialization Error pop box and then it asks if I want to download 4.5 - which wont work...   So I click No and it will not run the program...

Because it failed on that program before.  AA.exe failed once and now it will pop that message everytime I run it...  Even after it has been fixed.  I can test this by renaming the thing to BB.exe and it runs fine.  But rename it back to AA.exe and it wont run.  So, how can I clear this?  ( getting tired of renaming the program and the config file over and over as I add in new sections of code )

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I cleverly left the Config file in the directory with:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

in it.  the last bit there with it's suggestion that its 4.5 causes the problem.

I changed it to 4.0 and its all good now.  :-)  The reason the re-name test worked was because I just renamed the exe in testing and it had no related config file telling the computer that we were 4.5 when we were actually 4.0...